# Window.open not working IN IE

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
window.open("<%=mcrforHyperLink%>&fromDate="+fromDate+"&interfacen="+interfacen+"&interfaceid="+interfaceid+"&toDate="+toDate,'name_' +Math.floor(Math.random()*11),'height=680,width=900');
```

This is not in IE , but working fine under Mozilla .

please help .

Comment: Mozilla? That hasn't seen any development for half a decade. Do you mean Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer can't handle window names that include a space. You don't have one, but I'd bet it also has problems when they include a `.` character (which you are generating with Math.random`). Make sure your name contains just alphanumerics.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain why you are generating a random name for the window.
If you were to re-use it elsewhere I could understand.

This will do exactly the same unless there is something I have missed

`window.open("...",'_blank','height=680,width=900');`

(the ... is your url)

Also please notice that most modern browsers may BLOCK your window open unless instructed otherwise. If the url is from the same domain as the page with the script, I suggest you ajax it into the page you are on.